# Including a Xamarin binding library gives: No resource identifier found for attribute

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-binding

I have an existing Android (java) project which I have (been given and) built into an .aar and then added to a Xamarin Binding project with a build property of `LibraryProjectZip`. I then referenced the binding project from a Xamarin android project I have and I get this single lonely error:

> error APT0000: No resource identifier found for attribute 'coverage'
>   in package 'YourProj.YourProj'

The `coverage` it refers to seems to be a property for a library that is used by my initial .aar. It appears like this in a layout.xml: `ocr:coverage="5.5"`. Is there a way to tell the binder to ignore this or something?